# Change Spring RestTemplate logging

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate

I'm using spring restTemplate,
when I get a 403 response error code from a specific method restTemplate writes it to log as WARN I wold like to change only that line to INFO. is it possible?

```
WARN RestTemplate - GET request for "http://localhost:8080/xxx/xxx/internalKeepAlive" resulted in 403 (Forbidden); invoking error handler
```

Answer (score 0):

No, not possible. It is a WARN condition and it has been coded this way. What you could do is get the RestTemplate sources recompile them an change from log.warn to log.info :)